# Identity 2.0 Get Rolename and UserName by Linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I have Uploaded two images.

1. Image showing my edmx in visual studio 2013.
2. Image showing my tables in ssms.

I just wanted to show RoleName(Colmun [Name] in AspNetRoles Table) with UserName(Colmun [UserName] in AspNetUsers Table) in simple table (html) View i.e user with all respective roles.How can i do this using LINQ?[image: My Edmx][image: my Database]

**Update 1:** I do try like following but it didn't work

```
var result = from tb1 in context.Roles
             join tb2 in context.Users on tb1.Id equals tb2.Id
             select new { tb1.Name, tb2.UserName };
```

but its wrong actually i want `Userid` of all the user in `Role` table in place of `tb1.Id`[in Above LINQ Code] to match with `Userid` in `User` table [`tb2.Id`] . 
When i try to access Userid through Roles table which is coming like `Context.Roles.Users` coz `Users` here is a foreign Key for Roles Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for the above example

```
var result = from tb1 in context.Users
             from tb2 in tb1.Roles
             join tb3 in context.Roles on tb2.RoleId equals tb3.Id
             orderby tb1.UserName, tb3.Name /*optional*/
             select  new { tb3.Name, tb1.UserName }
```

But to meet your requiremets:

```
var result = from tb1 in context.Users
             from tb2 in tb1.Roles
             join tb3 in context.Roles on tb2.RoleId equals tb3.Id
             where tb3.Name == "Administrator"
             select  tb1.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maitain `[AspNetRoles.[Id]` column as primary key and `[AspNetUsers].[Id]` column as foriegn key.Lets write query like this

```
var result = (from R in context.AspNetRoles
             join U in context.AspNetUsers
             ON R.Id equals U.Id
             select new{
             RoleName=R.Name,
             UserName=U.UserName});
```

Comment: im using database first approach and the table you describe in query are only accessible through entities not by context and it return me an exception `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`. I donot know the problem but thanks anyway for your answer